If I use Map.get('key1') in angular template, does the change detection mechanism check the map value every cycle?
I know it is not a good practice to call expressions from a template in angular, because angular cannot predict whether the return value of a function has changed, so it needs to execute the function every time change detection runs.
My question is if angular will do the same behaviour for Map.get('key1') -> will it check the value of the map every change detection cycle, or no?
Also, any idea on how I can test this myself?
<ng-container *ngIf="myMap.get('key1')">....

Angular's change detection mechanism evaluates expressions in templates frequently. Calling expressions directly can lead to multiple evaluations, significantly impacting performance.
Using a variable to store the computation result, you ensure that the complex logic is executed only when explicitly needed, rather than during every change detection cycle.

Many people do not know the reason why not to use functions in HTML, so it's generally advised to never use them. But from my knowledge it's OK to do, as long as you are aware of the below explanation.

The rule of thumb is not to use resource-intensive actions on the HTML functions. Because they will get fired on each change detection.
To explain this; if we just use a property that stores a boolean in the HTML:
<div *ngIf="someBool">it's ok!</div>

But take the same scenario, for a find operation of an array:
<div *ngIf="showIfFound()">it's ok!</div>

TS:
arr: any = new Array(10000).fill(null);

ngOnInit() {
    this.arr[9999] = 1;
}

showIfFound() {
    return this.arr.find(x => x === 1);
}

Take the above code, it needs to loop 10000 rows for each change detection cycle, so the application slows down drastically.
Coming to your scenario, I think map.get() is O(1) complexity, so as the dataset increases, the look-up speed will be constant time, so I think you are good to use.

Thanks for your comment. As I understand, if you use functions in angular templates, they will be called on each detection cycle, which doesn't happen por simple properties, which is why its commonly preferable to use the latter. What I am wondering is if map.get() behaves like a simple property, and if angular only calls map.get() again if the value of map itself changes. Meanwhile, I'm using a pipe to achieve this, as pipes are only called if the value of the input changes

@JoséBate Even fi the property is accessed everytime the performance impact will be less when its O(1) time complexity, which is the case for your code, if you are really worried about this, just change this logic to a variable and update the variable everytime you expect a change to happen
